# Ingesting CSV data to MySQL DB in NiFi

Tags: mysql, sql, apache-nifi

I am trying to ingest the data of my CSV file into MySQL Db. My CSV file have field called '**MeasurementTime**' value as **2018-06-27 11:14.50**. My flow is taking that field as string and thus PutSQL is giving error. I am using the same template as per this [Template](https://community.hortonworks.com/storage/attachments/72972-csvtodbfinal.xml) but not using the **InferAvro processor** as i already have a pre-defined schema. This is the website [Website link](https://community.hortonworks.com/idea/192787/insert-csv-data-to-mysql-db.html)

How can I pass a Datetime field into my MySQL db as correct datatype and not as string. What setting should I change?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

With `PutDatabaseRecord` you can avoid all this chain of transformations and overengineering. The flow would be like:

```
GetFile -> PutDatabaseRecord
```

You need to configure `PutDatabaseRecord` with `RecordReader` property configured to `CSVReader` and configure `CSVReader` and set its `Schema Registry` to `AvroSchemaRegistry` and provide the valid schema. you can find the template for a sample flow [here](https://gist.github.com/zenfenan/9111703747dcf44a9cb6f2f7bb3f4d64).